# Getting frame from custom WPF user control

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, mvvm-light

I am developing a WinRT 8.1 application and I have a MenuFlyout within my custom control. Essentially, when a user clicks an Item within the MenuFlyout, the user is navigated to a different page. My dilemma is that I cannot access the Page element within my user control. Is there any work-around for this? I have looked at many similar SO questions, but none of them worked for me.

```
public sealed partial class BottomAppBar : UserControl {
  public BottomAppBar() {
     this.InitializeComponent();

     //we are forced to manually add items as flyout does not support command
     foreach (Vault v in User.Instance.Vaults) {
        MenuFlyoutItem vault = new MenuFlyoutItem();
        vault.Text = v.Name;
        vault.Click += switchUser;
        flyoutVault.Items.Add(vault);
     }
  }

  private void switchUser(object sender, object e) {
     //This line results in an error
     this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(LoginPage));

     /** Does not work as well
     var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);
     while (!(parent is Page)) {
        parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
     }
     (parent as Page).Frame.Navigate(typeof(LoginPage));
     */
  }
```

Comment: By WPF you mean the WinRT/XAML, right?

Answer (score 0):

The design-patterned solution is to create a navigation service passing the app frame to it and then use something like dependency injection to pass the navigation service to whomever might need it.

The simple solution is to store the reference to the Frame in your App class and access it through the app object/static property.